# Problem when exporting map from printlayout - openlayerplugin disappears

Tags: qgis, export, layouts

[image: Layout in print layout]

[image: Layout when printing]

I'm having problems with exporting map from printlayout to PDF or JPG. The Bing map I'm using is disappearing. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Can you please edit your question and add information about the software you using and the exact steps you were trying so others can recreate the problem?

Comment: I solved it now. I was using QGIS 2.16.3.

Comment: Ok, thank you! Please also consider posting your solution as an answer, so future users with the same problem can learn from it.